# Numbers: menu or list to jump to a specific sheet?

Tags: numbers

Is there a way to access a menu or list of all the sheets in a Numbers document, so I can quickly jump to one specific sheet without having to scroll or page one-by-one with the previous/next keyboard shortcuts?

I am looking for something similar to how the right-click on the sheet's tab will bring up a list of all the tables and graphs on that Sheet, so you can jump right to a specific table or graph.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to access a menu or list of all the sheets in a Numbers document, so I can quickly jump to one specific sheet without having to scroll or page one-by-one with the previous/next keyboard shortcuts?

The only way I know of is to **AppleScript** it and use some mechanism to trigger the *script*, e.g. an **Automator** *Service*<sup>1</sup>.

As an example, pressing **⌃⌘S** in **Numbers** with a **Stocks.numbers** document opened and frontmost, I get a `choose from list` *dialog box* as shown in the next image:

[image: Choose From List]

I then selected *sheet* **1-Year History** and then clicked **OK** and was taken to that *sheet* in the document. Note that *double-clicking* on any *list item* takes one to that *sheet* directly without having to click **OK** or press **Enter**. (You can also type the first character of the *list item* or use down/up arrow keys too.)

[image: Selected List Item]

Obviously with a **Numbers** document that has only five sheets this isn't really necessary, and is just an example for when the document has the number of sheets that would necessitate scrolling through the sheets tabs in the document to get to the one wanted. On my MBP 15" Retina display, I was able to see 37 sheets without having to scroll in the **Go To Sheet...** list box. (This will vary based on the screen resolution and height of the Dock.)

Create an **Automator** *Service*<sup>1</sup> as show in the next image:

[image: Automator Service]

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "Numbers" to set sheetList to name of every sheet of document 1

tell current application to activate
choose from list sheetList with title "Go To Sheet..." with prompt "Please select a sheet name:"
if the result is not false then
    my selectSheet(result as text)
end if

on selectSheet(n)
    try
        tell application "Numbers"
            activate
            -- # The following code causes Numbers to go to the selected sheet.
            -- # It is not modifying the existing data in the target cell, however,
            -- # it does cause a saved document to show as edited, temporarily, 
            -- # and resolved by the code in the following System Events tell block.
            set value of first cell of first table of sheet n of front document to ¬
                (value of first cell of first table of sheet n of front document)
        end tell

        tell application "System Events"
            -- # Undo Typing so the document doesn't show as edited if already saved,
            -- # and if already saved the modified date/time stamp shouldn't change.
            keystroke "z" using command down
            -- # Press the escape key to remove focus from cell A1.         
            key code 53
        end tell

    on error eStr number eNum
        display dialog eStr & " number " & eNum buttons {"OK"} ¬
            default button 1 with icon caution
        return
    end try
end selectSheet
```

---

<sub>**AppleScript Code Note:** As far as I know, **Numbers** does not have an explicit **AppleScript** *command* to select a given *sheet* and this is sort of an alternative method and it does cause a saved document to show as edited temporarily, even though it's not altering the *value* of the *target cell*, and resolved by the code in the System Events tell block. It works by setting the *value* of `cell "A1"` to it's *current value*, so while it's perceived as an edit, no *data* has been altered from its *current value* and if it was already saved, the modified date/time stamp shouldn't change. This works for me in **Numbers** 5.1 in **macOS High Sierra** on a *read-write* document, and is why I use it. As coded, it is not intended to be used on a *locked* or *read-only* document. Additional coding would be necessary for that scenario.</sub>

---

For **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**:

[image: Services Shortcut]

---

**Note:** Sometimes with an **Automator** *Service*<sup>1</sup> and assigning a *keyboard shortcut*, you may first have to trigger it from the target App's **Services** menu one time. From then on the *keyboard shortcut* should work normally.

<sub><sup>1</sup> In **macOS Mojave** an **Automator** *Service* is called a *Quick Action*.</sub>

---

Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans the included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).